# Setting Single Node Hadoop Cluster on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and trying to setup single node cluster on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have followed Michel Nall's tutorial. There is a problem with this cluster... sometimes it runs and sometimes it stops without any reason.
When a cluster is running... it won't allow me to run the Java mapper and reducers.

Can't figure out the problem. Can anyone help me with step by step installation and usage help.
here are the code and errors:

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

  public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
     private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
     private Text word = new Text();    
     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       String line = value.toString();
       StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
       while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
         word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
         output.collect(word, one);
       }
     }
   }

   public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       int sum = 0;
       while (values.hasNext()) {
         sum += values.next().get();
       }
       output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
     conf.setJobName("wordcount");

     conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
     conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
     conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

     conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
     conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

     FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

     JobClient.runJob(conf);
   }
}
```

Errors are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:139)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: What does the log show? How can you tell it's not running? Do you get an exception in one of the required services?

Comment: Meenal, welcome to stackoverflow. In order to improve the chances of getting an answer, please post as many details as you can such as error logs to support each of the problem that you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting en exception which is Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging

Above class LogFactory is not present at org/apache/commons/logging/ path. 
You have to be sure that whether it there or not.